# How to design database model

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

In my application user have to configure application before first running. So I have form where user have to set few comboboxes.
Based on user selection I have to show in my application few fields.

Example:

1. Combobox1 - posibility values: use, don't use
2. Combobox2 - posibility values: I agree, I don't agree
3. Combobox3 - posibility values: I have, I don't have

After running application I have to show:

1. TextBox - if user choosed: ((use or I agree) and I don't have)
2. Label   - if user choosed: (don't use and I don't have)

In my database I have to create table where I can put user configuration.

```
Configuration_Fields_Table                Fields_to_show
Id   Name         Value                   Id   Name
1    Combobox1    use                     1    TextBox
2    Combobox1    don't use               2    Label
3    Combobox2    I agree                 3    Grid
4    Combobox2    I don't agree
5    Combobox3    I have
6    Combobox3    I don't have

MappingTable
Id   Field_to_show_id  Conf_Field_id
1    1                 1
2    1                 3
3    1                 6
4    2                 2
5    2                 6
```

I have problem with MappingTable. Once I have OR condition, once AND condition.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: It would be easier to write code. What framework are you planning on using?

Comment: I have to put this data to database because this is teacher requirement. I have to create WPF application (MVVM) and I have to use Prism framework.

Comment: Well the first problem I see with this is that you don't have the Userid anywhere so how are you going to relate the mapping to the specific user configuration?.

Comment: To be clear, you are designing the database yourself not using one provided by the teacher?

Comment: For simplicity, there is only one user. Yes, this is my database model.